# How can I use swing jProgressBar in java to increment upto 100% while inserting records from jTable to Database?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I have tried to do the following code but the problem is jProgressBar only updates and increment by a value when all the action is complement. I would wish the bar to increment step by step progressively since it is a heavy task being executed.

```
    excelProgressBar.setValue(0);
    allLabel1.setText("");
    allLabel2.setText("");

    DefaultTableModel ImportFromExcelFormModel = (DefaultTableModel) importExcelTable.getModel();
    int jTableRows = importExcelTable.getRowCount();

    allLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(jTableRows));

    for (int i = 0; i < jTableRows; i++) {

        excelProgressBar.setValue(i + 1);

        importedExcelMemberName = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        importedExcelIDNumber = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
        importedExcelMemberNumber = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
        importedExcelPayrollNo = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
        importedExcelSalaryAccount = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
        importedExcelCellphone = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
        importedExcelEmployer = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 6).toString();
        importedExcelJan = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 7).toString();
        importedExcelFeb = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 8).toString();
        importedExcelMarch = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 9).toString();
        importedExcelApril = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 10).toString();
        importedExcelMay = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 11).toString();
        importedExcelJune = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 12).toString();
        importedExcelJuly = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 13).toString();
        importedExcelAugust = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 14).toString();
        importedExcelSept = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 15).toString();
        importedExcelOctober = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 16).toString();
        importedExcelNovemebr = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 17).toString();
        importedExcelDecember = ImportFromExcelFormModel.getValueAt(i, 18).toString();

        now = LocalDateTime.now();
        captureDate = dtf1.format(now);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tntdividend", "root", "");

            ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO dividedpayslip( MemberName, IDNumber, MemberNo, PayrollNo, SalaryAccount, CellPhoneNo, "
                    + "Employer, Jan, Feb, March, April, May, June, July, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, DecMonth ) " 
                    + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            ps.setString(1, importedExcelMemberName);
            ps.setString(2, importedExcelIDNumber);
            ps.setString(3, importedExcelMemberNumber);
            ps.setString(4, importedExcelPayrollNo);
            ps.setString(5, importedExcelSalaryAccount);
            ps.setString(6, importedExcelCellphone);
            ps.setString(7, importedExcelEmployer);
            ps.setString(8, importedExcelJan);
            ps.setString(9, importedExcelFeb);
            ps.setString(10, importedExcelMarch);
            ps.setString(11, importedExcelApril);
            ps.setString(12, importedExcelMay);
            ps.setString(13, importedExcelJune);
            ps.setString(14, importedExcelJuly);
            ps.setString(15, importedExcelAugust);
            ps.setString(16, importedExcelSept);
            ps.setString(17, importedExcelOctober);
            ps.setString(18, importedExcelNovemebr);
            ps.setString(19, importedExcelDecember);

            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
            con.close();

            allLabel2.setText(String.valueOf(dcf.format(jTableRows)));

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, " Error !!", "Error!" + e, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        allLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(dcf.format(i + 1)));

        System.out.println("Inserted " + i);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dcf.format(jTableRows) + " Records Processed Successfully");
    excelProgressBar.setValue(0);
```

The above code works well and data is well inserted to my database. The big problem is that the progress bar only updates fast at the end of the program after waiting for about 7 minutes. Please help.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. BTW - establishing the connection to the DB from inside a loop seems a bad idea. Establish the link outside the loop and it will likely go much more quickly.

Comment: Thank, I have established the connection outside the loop and the code is a bit lighter ...a bit fast. I will learn more about EDT @AndrewThompson

Comment: *I have established the connection outside the loop and the code is a bit lighter * - yes, that will help, but was not the key point of the answer. The key point is to use a separate Thread so the GUI can keep responding to events and repaint itself. The easiest way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker` and publish results as they become available. This is covered in the tutorial.

Comment: Completed well ... thank you so much @camickr Thompson. I have learnt the trick out through SwingWorker and Threads.

Comment: Completed well ... thank you so much @AndrewThompson ...I have learnt the trick out through SwingWorker and Threads.